# Excel is not opening csv file without .csv extension properly

Tags: excel, csv, spreadsheet

The columns in a csv file are grouped together into column A if
the file has a different extension other than .csv

I have to use Data > Text To Columns and change the delimiter from '\t' to ','
to format the contents properly.

Can I tell Excel say to treat .ext as a .csv file?

Comment: Just to be more precise, I have a huge set of datafiles with extension .ext but they are really csv files. I view these files regularly and so it's annoying to go through the Text Import Wizard every time I need to view a file. I am not allowed to change the extension .ext to .csv

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, I've usually removed the extension from the file altogether. In Excel 2007, if I take a file `filename.ext` and change that to `filename` before opening it, it forces Excel's Text Import Wizard to open:

[image]

Other than that, I don't know of an Excel setting to map file extensions to specific behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking on the `all files` dropdown menu when you navigate to the file?

[image]